# How to convert a string date to a different timezone using Java 8

Tags: java

I have a simple test where I need to take a date in string format and convert it to a different timezone. I can assume the date/time will be in the local time zone.

I have the following:

```
    @Test
    public void covertTimestampsTest() {
    String stringDate = "2016-02-26 13:48:09";
    TemporalAccessor t = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(stringDate );
    LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.from(t);
    ZonedDateTime zldt = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));

    System.out.println(ldt);
    System.out.println(zldt);
}
```

What I get is the following:

2016-02-26T13:48:09\n
2016-02-26T13:48:09Z[UTC]

I've read several different tutorials where they work with the current time and everything seems to work. I can't get it to work with dates that are not current.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat class would also work fine here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: Please re-open this Question. This Question asks about the java.time framework built into Java 8 and later. The supposed duplicate original asks about the Joda-Time library. So unrelated, not a duplicate.

Comment: @socallcheesehead If you want to assign the JVM’s current default time zone, why are you assigning the UTC time zone? Replace `ZoneId.of("UTC")` with [`ZoneId.systemDefault()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#systemDefault--). If you want Montréal, use [`ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" )`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html#of-java.lang.String-).  The rest of your code is correct. BTW, when you do need UTC, use convenient constant in the subclass [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC).

Comment: @BasilBourque the timestamp in the string is the timezone of the client, i need to convert that to say colombia "America/Bogota" but when i apply the timezone and then print it the hour and minute remain the same. Not sure if i have the wrong expectations of how it should work

Comment: "Local…" means "with no particular time zone assigned". So a “Local…” is *not* an actual moment on the timeline. Has no meaning until you apply a time zone. If the String was meant to represent a date-time in Seattle, assign `America/Los_Angeles`. If the string represents Bogota, pass Bogota to the `atZone` method. To re-assign a `ZonedDateTime` to a different time zone, call `withZoneSameInstant`.